# Terraria is not running smoothly at all,

Tags: games, steam

I've set up Proton GE-1 6.16 and Terraria just won't run smoothly, it strives to 60fps but still stutters quite a bit, still playable. I have a GTX 1660ti and I am using nvidia-driver-470.

Comment: Regarding the recommended specs, it should work fine. However, why do you use Proton when the game is available on Steam for Linux?

Comment: I am using proton because if I don't the game runs in slow mo for some reason /: but regardless of that, i assume that game that i will need to use proton for will run just as bad, ubuntu entirely runs pretty bad for me, and not smooth at all, i want to use it so bad but nothing seems to go my way, and i love it